# Integrating factor method to integrate $\frac{dT}{dt} = - k(T-T_a)$

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\frac{dT}{dt} = - k(T-T_a)$$
Where T(t) is the temperature of the object at time t, $T_a$ is the ambient temperature and k is a positive constant.

I know this can be easily solved by the separable variable method however, I’m trying to solve it using the integrating factor method which has to be in the form of $\frac{dy}{dx} + p(x) \cdot y = f(x) $

is this possible? I heard that it is possible with assumptions but I am not sure how to go with it.

Comment: Why don't you write $\frac{dT}{dt}+kT=kT_{a}$? Here, $p(t)=k$ and $f(t)=kT_{a}$

Comment: @MateusRocha thanks a lot!! didn’t thought of expanding the function but rather I just brought over the whole expression to the left hand side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expand and move terms to get into standard form $$\frac{dT}{dt} + kT = kT_0$$

Your integrating factor is $e^{whatever\, is\, next\, to\, T}$ in this case the k is next to T

$$e^{\int k dt} = e^{kt}$$

Multiply everything by integrating factor

$$\frac{dT}{dt}e^{kt} + kT e^{kt} = kT_0e^{kt}$$

Separate out the derivative

$$\frac{d}{dT}[Te^{kt}] = kT_0 e^{kt}$$

Integrate both sides
$$Te^{kt} = \int kT_0 e^{kt} dt$$

$$Te^{kt} = kT_0 \frac{e^{kt}}{k} +C$$

Divide both sides by $e^{kt}$ and simplify

$$T = \frac{kT_0 e^{kt}}{k e^{kt}} + Ce^{-kt}$$
$$T = T_0 + Ce^{-kt}$$